# Jquery plugin for date selecting

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a Jquery plugin that exposes a date input as 3 select boxes and manages the chosen date in a hidden input inside the form.

I remember seen it a long time ago but at that time a datepicker was more appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [selectboxutils](http://chris4403.blogspot.com/2007/12/jquery-plugins-easy-to-create-numeric.html) might work for you.  Check out the datePulldown example on [this page](http://dev.chrisryu.com/data/jQuery-selectbox-utils/demo/index.html).

Comment: It isn't the plugin I had in mind, but it definetly helps. Thanks.